# How can I input array using SOAPUI?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

Below is the WSDL format for customerNames.

```
<xsd:element name="CustomersNames" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Please Advice that how can i pass input to test soap request using SOAPUI.

```
<CustomersNames>--inpuhere--</CustomersNames>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass Customer name like below.

```
<CustomersNames>Andrew</CustomersNames>
<CustomersNames>Mohan</CustomersNames>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <arg0>5401</arg0>
     <arg0>5401</arg0>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <arg1>0904</arg1>
     <arg1>0904</arg1>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <arg2>20150101</arg2>
     <arg2>20150101</arg2>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <arg3>20170101</arg3>
     <arg3>20170101</arg3>
```

I am getting data like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> method (List<String> A,
                         List<String> B,
                         List<String> C,
                         List<String> D) {
```

It works for me!